# Failure to import numpy in Jupyter notebook

Tags: numpy, import, ipython, importerror, jupyter

I am new to iPython/Jupyter. Python skills limited, but learning. I am trying to import numpy as np and get the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-4ee716103900> in <module>()
----> 1 import numpy as np

/Users/jmmiii/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py in <module>()
    166         return loader(*packages, **options)
    167 
--> 168     from . import add_newdocs
    169     __all__ = ['add_newdocs', 'ModuleDeprecationWarning']
    170 

/Users/jmmiii/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py in <module>()
     11 from __future__ import division, absolute_import, print_function
     12 
---> 13 from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
     14 
     15 ###############################################################################

/Users/jmmiii/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py in <module>()
      6 from numpy.version import version as __version__
      7 
----> 8 from .type_check import *
      9 from .index_tricks import *
     10 from .function_base import *

/Users/jmmiii/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py in <module>()
      9            'common_type']
     10 
---> 11 import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
     12 from numpy.core.numeric import asarray, asanyarray, array, isnan, \
     13                 obj2sctype, zeros

/Users/jmmiii/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py in <module>()
      4 from numpy.version import version as __version__
      5 
----> 6 from . import multiarray
      7 from . import umath
      8 from . import _internal # for freeze programs

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/jmmiii/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/jmmiii/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

I have several python installs on my Mac, which has Yosemite, including Canopy and Anaconda. I want my Jupyter notebook to use the Anaconda install including all the modules, libraries, etc. associated with it. It seems however that jupyter is targeting Canopy instead.  Thus, I think my problem might stem from the wrong linkage.

**QUESTION 1**: Does my conclusion hold water? If not, what might I be missing?

**QUESTION 2**: How can I direct/link jupyter with Anaconda and not with Canopy so that I import everything from anaconda only?

Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

You can either set the PATH to execute python commands from the ~/anaconda/bin directory by prepending it to your .bah_profile by running the following command.

```
export PATH="/Users/jmmiii/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

OR, you can create an alias for the command by editing your ~/.bash_profile and adding:

```
alias jupyter-notebook="/Users/jmmiii/anaconda/bin/jupyter-notebook"
```

Comment: Thanks John! I will tuck that away for future reference. Frustrated, i actually completely uninstalled Anaconda and reinstalled it. It now works when I load an iPython notebook, but not a Jupyter notebook. However, this is not a bother. I appreciate the hints above, particularly on the alias assignment.