# Numpy and Pandas Not Working in Jupyter Notebook on Mac

Tags: macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have both Python 2.7 and 3.6 working on my machine. Numpy and Pandas both load, for either version of Python, in the terminal. However, when I try to access them from inside Jupyter notebook, I get the following error messages:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-4ee716103900> in <module>()
----> 1 import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'


ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-af55e7023913> in <module>()
----> 1 import pandas as pd

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Here is a screenshot of the problem as well:

[image]

If you look in the top right hand corner of the screenshot, you will notice where it says "Python3". I have seen video tutorials on Jupyter where clicking on that button generates a drop down list, allowing users to select alternate versions of Python. However, when I click on that button, nothing happens.

I noticed that a similar question was asked before here:

[numpy & pandas 'ModuleNotFoundEror' in Jupyter notebook (Python 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43872617/numpy-pandas-modulenotfounderor-in-jupyter-notebook-python-3)

However, very little information was provided and no resolution seems to have been found.

Another similar question provided a hint at an answer that was slightly more promising. It suggested running the following code both from terminal and from inside Jupyter, to make sure they match.

```
import sys; sys.executable
```

[failed to import numpy as np when I worked with jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42500649/failed-to-import-numpy-as-np-when-i-worked-with-jupyter-notebook)

From terminal using Python 2.7.10>>

```
import sys; sys.executable
'/usr/bin/python'
```

From terminal using Python 3.6.1>>

```
import sys; sys.executable
'/usr/local/bin/python3'
```

From Jupyter>>

```
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6'
```

Comment: what other imports have you tried? Can you import from the standard library - what about from `IPython`?

Comment: I can import and run Numpy from either IPython or IPython3, without issue. However, when I run `jupyter notebook` from terminal it does not work. What I just discovered, which is fascinating, is that if I launch Jupyter from Anaconda Navigator it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked this solution:
[Failure to import numpy in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239739/failure-to-import-numpy-in-jupyter-notebook) ?

In your Jupyter screenshot, you're using a Python 3 kernel.
Make sure you have NumPy (and any others you might want to use) installed in your selected Python 3 environment.

Comment: As I mentioned in the second sentence, not only are the installed, but they load in either environment.

Comment: What's the output of `$ whereis jupyter` and `$ which jupyter`?